Set of primitive idempotents of group algebras
Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ be a field with characteristic zero. Can we construct the set of primitive orthogonal idempotents of $KG$? By this set, I mean the set of idempotents such that $e_ie_j=0$ for $i \ne j$ and idempotents cannot be decomposed into a sum of two orthogonal idempotents.
As far as I know, $KG$ is semisimple so $KG=KGe_1 \times \cdots \times KGe_m$, where $KGe_i$ is a two-sided minimal ideal and $e_i=\frac{\dim_K(W_i)}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\chi_i(g^{-1})g$ is the primitive central idempotent or centrally primitive idempotent corresponding to the irreducible $K$-representation $W_i$ of $G$ with character $\chi_i$. Here, each $KGe_i$ is a simple algebra and has a set of primitive orthogonal idempotents. This set has $\frac{\dim_K(W_i)}{\dim_K(End_G(W_i))}$ elements namely $e_{ij}$; $1 \le j \le \frac{\dim_K(W_i)}{\dim_K(End_G(W_i))}$. We have $\sum_{j}e_{ij}=e_i$ and each $KGe_ie_{ij}=KGe_{ij}$ is a minimal left ideal of $KGe_i$.
Do you know how we can construct $e_{ij}$?
Could you give me a reference for this? (I am mostly interested in the case where $K=\mathbb{R}$)
I saw some papers on constructing such elements for particular $K$ and $G$. For example, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10468-010-9244-4
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2022.2162063
https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/0000-000-00/S0025-5718-2024-03937-6/
I have also seen some other papers for constructing such idempotents when $K$ is a finite field, motivated by coding theory.
I would like to know a book that has a comprehensive discussion about these when $K$ has characteristic zero, preferably $K=\mathbb{R}$. I know such a construction should exist since the paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-019-01874-9 claimed it in section 3.3. My knowledge is just not enough to understand the paper fully without other resources.
